# Bar graph is not rendering

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm trying to duplicate this code found on [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), but I can't get my bar graph to render.  I'm pulling from a csv instead of a tsv, but I don't think that would made a difference.  There aren't any errors written to the console.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {                        
        loadChart();
    });

    function loadChart() {
        var svg = d3.select("svg");
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0,width]).padding(0.1),
            y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

        var g = svg.append(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.csv("Data/data.csv", function(d) {
            d.NumProducts = +d.NumProducts;
            return d;
        }, function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Category; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.NumProducts; })]);

            g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

            g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10))
                .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("Dy", "0.71em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Number of Products");

            g.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class" , "bar")
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Category); })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.NumProducts); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.NumProducts); });
        });
    }
</script>
```

The csv:

```
Category,NumProducts
Beverages,12
Condiments,12
Confections,13
Dairy Products,10
Grains/Cereals,7
Meat/Poultry,6
Produce,5
Seafood,12
```

Comment: also please put in your CSV up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that you have is down to missing speech marks.

```
 var g = svg.append(g)
```

Should read:

```
 var g = svg.append("g")
```

If you were to inspect your DOM you would see

```
<svg>
    <undefined transform="translate(40,20)">
    ... (correct DOM)
    </undefined>
</svg>
```

The reason that nothing renders after this point, is because the browser doesn't know how to render an `<undefined>` element, therefore it stops trying to render.

This immediately indicated that one of the `append` calls wasn't working because the DOM didn't understand the type of element given to it. Making the change produces this:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? - this addresses the original question pretty accurately

Comment: I new it would be something small, but I couldn't see it.  Thanks!